# Every crash shown as android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable, Not the correct exception is shown in playstore

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, crash-reports

I cannot pinpoint to what caused the crash from the crash log inside Playstore console all it shows is android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable. 
Some times the place is also shown but the orginal exception that gets thrown is not shown . Its a cross platform xamarin forms application.
In my case log looks like

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at StackCardView.Com.Wenchao.Cardstack.CardStack.ICardEventListener.Discarded (System.Int32 p0, System.Int32 p1) [0x00000] in <9395370f1a304c7290a7531b2c3dfd4d>:0
at Com.Wenchao.Cardstack.CardStack+ICardEventListenerInvoker.n_Discarded_II (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Int32 p0, System.Int32 p1) [0x00009] in <54ad445d01d649f18c501aeb89761ae6>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:97ca24d4-0414-43c1-a8ee-a1e52f293935 (intptr,intptr,int,int)
  at md5d9e2c345da228fe4f95e9f8464432261.StackCardView.n_discarded (Native Method)
  at md5d9e2c345da228fe4f95e9f8464432261.StackCardView.discarded (StackCardView.java:50)
  at com.wenchao.cardstack.CardStack$2$1.onAnimationEnd (CardStack.java:184)
  at com.wenchao.cardstack.CardAnimator$3.onAnimationEnd (CardAnimator.java:178)
  at android.animation.AnimatorSet$AnimatorSetListener.onAnimationEnd (AnimatorSet.java:855)
  at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation (ValueAnimator.java:1239)
  at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame (ValueAnimator.java:766)
  at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler$1.run (ValueAnimator.java:801)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:920)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:695)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:628)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:906)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7224)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**2. Log**

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at CustomControls.Droid.FButtonRenderer.SetUserDetails (Xamarin.Facebook.GraphResponse json) [0x00006] in <9395370f1a304c7290a7531b2c3dfd4d>:0
     at JiTr.Core.CustomControls.Droid.FButtonRenderer.OnSuccessfulLogin (Xamarin.Facebook.GraphResponse json, System.String token) [0x0000a] in <9395370f1a304c7290a7531b2c3dfd4d>:0
     at JiTr.Core.CustomControls.Droid.FButtonRenderer+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<OnElementChanged>b__1 (Xamarin.Facebook.GraphResponse json) [0x00008] in <9395370f1a304c7290a7531b2c3dfd4d>:0
     at JiTr.Core.CustomControls.Droid.FButtonRenderer+GraphCallBack`1[TResult].OnCompleted (Xamarin.Facebook.GraphResponse p0) [0x00011] in <9395370f1a304c7290a7531b2c3dfd4d>:0
     at Xamarin.Facebook.GraphRequest+ICallbackInvoker.n_OnCompleted_Lcom_facebook_GraphResponse_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_response) [0x00012] in <03649d48fbd74f219fa81f56f16154fd>:0
     at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:7e8b0ee9-7c65-4842-80d5-946db81633f7 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

How to properly pinpoint what actually caused the issue.

Comment: In your crash raport you have inner exception. Look there.

Comment: Only this much is shown in google play console!(Its a cross platform xamarin forms application) Should i do something in codebase to send the inner exceptions also

Comment: Are you using the [AndroidSwipeableCardStack](https://github.com/wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack) lib ? Is this 
`StackCardView` in a Xamarin.Forms `ListView`?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT i converted this project to a DLL and used in forms for swipeable cards

Comment: not inside listview

Comment: I found it to be a null pointer expection,but dunno why :(

Comment: Would you mind sharing a basic demo that can reproduce the problem through online repo?

Comment: You mean the issue with the stackCard or the exception header not showing?